# How can I use an enhanced keyboard and mouse with a KVM?

Tags: usb, keyboard, hdmi, dvi, kvm-switch

What technical solutions can enable multimedia keyboards and multi-button mice to operate with a 4-port DVI or HDMI KVM switch such as the Avocent 4SVDVI10-001?

Comment: One reason this question was closed is that shopping recommendations become outdated very fast. See also [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) for an explanation why those questions are off topic here.

Comment: I have a Belkin SOHO KVM. I use a Microsoft Multimedia keyboard that includes 16 + 3 extra buttons along the top of the keyboard for *"Multimedia"* and other purposes. I also use a Microsoft 5 button mouse (Intellimouse Explorer). Everything worked together *"out of the box"*, with no special configuration changes or drivers... just plug-and-play.